# NSLayoutConstraint ivar init with self as an item in UIView subclass in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, initialization, nslayoutconstraint

I have a subclass of UIView which uses some NSLayoutConstraint instances declared as ivars using Swift. The reason for them to be ivars is that I change the constant value. One of them is related to self:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: .Right, 
                   relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, 
                   multiplier: 1, constant: self.contentViewWidth)
```

As you know, all ivars should be initialized before calling to a superclass init, but you can't refer to self only after superclass init. Also, you can't change the toItem (second item) value after the NSLayoutConstraint instance has been initialized.

Before Swift 1.2 marking an ivar with an exclamation mark (implicitly unwrapped value) told the compiler that you're responsible for this ivar to be non-nil when needed, so you can initialize the ivar wherever you want until you're sure it won't be used before that code has been called. That's what I used: I made this NSLayoutConstraint implicitly unwrapped and initialized just after the super.init call, so the self could be referenced:

```
class FilterView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private let contentRightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

    init(frame: CGRect, customMode: Bool = false) {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        contentRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, 
        attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, 
        attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: self.contentViewWidth)
    }
}
```

Since Swift 1.2 the solution above doesn't work anymore. I found two workarounds for this:

1) replace let with var and use a dummy value:

```
class FilterView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var contentRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

    init(frame: CGRect, customMode: Bool = false) {
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
    contentRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, 
        attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, 
        attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: self.contentViewWidth)
    }
}
```

It's not good because it make the ivar changeable and creates an unnecessary instance.

2) Use a lazy var:

```
class FilterView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private lazy var contentRightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = 
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView, attribute: .Right, 
        relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Right, 
        multiplier: 1, constant: self.contentViewWidth)
}
```

This is better, but still is changeable though should be `let`.

Does anybody have other ideas?

Comment: Pedantic point: ivars are an Objective C thing, where as Swift has properties. But the question is a good one that I'd like to know the answer to as well.

Comment: One more thing... If using `var` instead of `let` implicitly unwrapped values can still be used in the same way as before Swift 1.2. So, currently it's an even better approach than those two I mentioned. But still not `let`.